# Remove all textbox from Panel control with Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I´m trying to remove `textbox` controls from a `panel` in a event Button click:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   panel1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToList().Clear();
}
```

but it doesn´t work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why your approach is not working, is that you are creating a new List, not connected to the panel (your `ToList` call), then clearing that list, effectively doing nothing.

You need to remove each item on the `Controls` collection directly:

```
 var textBoxes = panel1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToList();
 foreach(var box in textBoxes)
     panel1.Controls.Remove(box);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove the controls from the form rather than simply clear their contents (or removing them from a list that you just created), you need to remove them from the Panel. You can still accomplish this via a one-liner though:

```
panel1.Controls
      .OfType<TextBox>()
      .ToList()
      .ForEach(t => panel1.Controls.Remove(t));
```